# How to setup server file to read the right folder for NextJS app hosted on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, next.js

Hopefully, this will be my last question regarding NextJS.

I finally moved all of my React components to NextJS and I'm in the step of uploading it to Heroku.

The usual code for a React app looks like this:

```js
if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
  process.env.NODE_TECHNOLOGY === `react`
) {
  // This is for ReactJS
  app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), 'client-app/build')))
  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(path.resolve(), 'client-app', 'build', 'index.html')
    )
  )
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: 'API is running',
      time: new Date().toISOString(),
    })
  })
}
```

I then tried adding an else-if statement for NextJS:

```js
if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
  process.env.NODE_TECHNOLOGY === `react`
) {
  // This is for ReactJS
  app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), 'client-app/build')))
  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(path.resolve(), 'client-app', 'build', 'index.html')
    )
  )
} else if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
  process.env.NODE_TECHNOLOGY === `next`
) {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), 'client-next-app/build')))
  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(path.resolve(), 'client-next-app', 'build', 'index.html')
    )
  )
} else {
  // This is for NextJS production
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: 'API is running',
      time: new Date().toISOString(),
    })
  })
}
```

However, I'm still unsure what I am supposed to submit because after running the `npm run build` command, next returns this file structure:
[image: File structure returned from NextJS command]

I already modified my nextJS `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  },
```

and this is what my top-folder `package.json` file looks like:

```json
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client-react": "npm start --prefix client-app",
    "client-next": "npm run dev --prefix client-next-app",
    "devreact": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client-react\" \"npx peer --port PORT\" ",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client-next\" \"npx peer --port PORT\" ",
    "debug": "ndb server",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client-next-app && npm run build --prefix client-next-app"
  },
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I decided to host the project in Vercel. Damn easy.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.